How do you save user data to firestore database?
When using the iOS simulator to run my app when i register users their email and uid gets saved to the auth. But the users data does not get saved to the firestore database to create a collection.
This happens with both my register data and my user post data.
The problem is I can see in my firebase console in authentication tab that many new users getting authenticated but users data isn't being stored in firestore.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<void> registerUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String fullName,
  }) async {
    try {
      // Create a new user with email and password
      print('Attempting to create user with email: $email');
      UserCredential newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      print('User created successfully');

      // Add the user's email, full name, and default role to Firestore
      if (newUser.user != null) {
        print('Saving user metadata');
        await _firestore.collection('usermetadata').doc(newUser.user!.uid).set({
          'email': email,
          'full_name': fullName,
          'role': 'user', // Default role, you can change this as needed
        }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
          throw TimeoutException('Saving user metadata timed out');
        });
        print('User metadata saved successfully');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error registering user: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  }

  Future<User?> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      return _auth.currentUser;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Something went wrong with getting current logged in user");
    }
  }

  Future<String?> getUserRole() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final doc = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
      return doc.data()?['role'] as String?;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:campusu/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:campusu/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:campusu/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:campusu/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud_nsn/modal_progress_hud_nsn.dart';

class NewRegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewRegistrationScreen({super.key});

  static String id = 'new_registration_screen';

  @override
  State<NewRegistrationScreen> createState() => _NewRegistrationScreenState();
}

class _NewRegistrationScreenState extends State<NewRegistrationScreen> {
  final Auth _authService = Auth();
  bool showSpinner = false;
  late String email;
  late String password;
  late String userFullName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 0.0),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  userFullName = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your full name.'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your email.'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your password.'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              RoundedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    print('Attempting to register user');
                    await _authService.registerUser(
                      email: email,
                      password: password,
                      fullName: userFullName,
                    );
                    print('User registered successfully');

                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);

                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } catch (e) {
                    print('Error during registration: $e');
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                buttonText: 'Register',
              ),
              kDivider,
              const Text(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                "Already registered?",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  'Login',
                  style: kHyperlinkTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:campusu/components/custom_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:campusu/components/menu_bars.dart';
import 'package:campusu/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:campusu/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:campusu/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class CreatePost extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreatePost({super.key});

  static const String id = "create_post";

  @override
  State<CreatePost> createState() => _CreatePostState();
}

class _CreatePostState extends State<CreatePost> {
  final TextEditingController _contentTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _linkTextController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _contentFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final uuid = Uuid();

  File? _image;
  String _content = "";
  String _link = "";
  late final User? loggedInUser;

  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() => _image = imageTemp);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> savePost({
    required String content,
    required File? image,
    required String userID,
    required String schoolID,
    required String clubID,
    String? link,
  }) async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final uniqueID = uuid.v1();
    final postImageRef = storageRef.child("uploads/posts/$uniqueID");

    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user == null) {
        print('User not authenticated.');
        return;
      }

      String imageUrl = "";
      if (image != null) {
        await postImageRef.putFile(image);
        imageUrl = await postImageRef.getDownloadURL();
        print('Image uploaded successfully: $imageUrl');
      }

      final postData = <String, dynamic>{
        'active': true,
        'club': clubID,
        'content': content,
        'created_at': Timestamp.now(),
        'image': imageUrl,
        'school': schoolID,
        'user': userID,
        'link': link,
      };

      await _firestore.collection('posts').add(postData);
      print('Post saved successfully: $postData');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving post: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loggedInUser = _auth.currentUser;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dynamic> _fetchUserMetadata() async {
    final user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
      return null;
    } else {
      try {
        print('Fetching user metadata for user_id: ${user.uid}');
        DocumentSnapshot userMetadataSnapshot = await _firestore
            .collection('usermetadata')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .get();

        if (userMetadataSnapshot.exists) {
          dynamic userData = userMetadataSnapshot.data();
          print('User metadata found: $userData');
          return userData;
        } else {
          print('User metadata document not found for user_id: ${user.uid}');
          return null;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error fetching user metadata: $e');
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextField(
              controller: _contentTextController,
              focusNode: _contentFocusNode,
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: "Write your post content here...",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              maxLines: 5,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _content = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextField(
              controller: _linkTextController,
              decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: "Add a link (optional)",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _link = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            if (_image != null)
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: Image.file(
                  _image!,
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await pickImage();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.photo_library),
              label: const Text("Add Photo"),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RoundedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (loggedInUser != null) {
                  final userMetadata = await _fetchUserMetadata();
                  if (userMetadata != null) {
                    final userSchool = userMetadata['school'] ?? "";
                    final userClub = userMetadata['club'] ?? "";

                    if (_content.isNotEmpty) {
                      await savePost(
                        content: _content,
                        image: _image,
                        userID: loggedInUser!.uid,
                        schoolID: userSchool,
                        clubID: userClub,
                        link: _link.isNotEmpty ? _link : null,
                      );
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    } else {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Post content cannot be empty.')),
                      );
                    }
                  } else {
                    print('User metadata is null for user_id: ${loggedInUser!.uid}');
                  }
                } else {
                  print('Logged in user is null.');
                }
              },
              color: kPrimaryColor,
              buttonText: 'Post',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomMenuBar(),
    );
  }
}


My database rules give users the option to read and write but still no data is being added to the firestore.
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Rule for user profiles
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    // Rule for posts
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    // Rule for user metadata
    match /usermetadata/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    // Rule for basicCollection
    match /basicCollection/{documentId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}


